# "Normality" condition on an ordinal operator.

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Call a rule $\Phi:\Bbb{ON}\rightarrow\Bbb{ON}$ *normal* if for any ordinal $\alpha$, $\Phi(\alpha)<\Phi(\alpha^+)$, and for limit ordinals $\lambda$, $\Phi(\lambda)=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}\Phi(\alpha)$.

Prove that for all non-zero ordinals $\beta$, the rule $\alpha\mapsto\alpha+\beta$ is not normal. (and that $\alpha\mapsto\beta+\alpha$ is normal, but that's an easy induction)

Now, possibly the question is ill-formulated and wants us to prove only that that rule is not normal for some $\beta$. I have the solution below, but I don't see why it provides an answer. To me, it proves that for $\alpha<\beta .\omega$ we have $\alpha + \beta.\omega<\beta.\omega + \beta.\omega$, but that doesn't seem to go against the normality condition for limit ordinals...

Am I not seeing something obvious?

[image: ans]

Comment: If $b=1$ and $\phi(a)=a+1$ for all $a$  then $ \phi(a^+)=a^+ + 1\ge  (a+1)+1>(a+1)=\phi(a).$

Comment: Normally $\alpha^+$ is the successor *cardinal*, i.e. the least initial ordinal larger than $\alpha$. We use $\alpha+1$ to denote the successor *ordinal* of $\alpha$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I don't understand the point of your comment. Yes, the function $\alpha\mapsto\alpha+1$ satisfies the first condition in the definition of normality, but it fails the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative (easier, I think) proof: Let $\Phi(\alpha) = \alpha+\beta$.

If $\omega\leq \beta$, then $\Phi(\alpha+1) = \alpha+1+\beta = \alpha+\beta = \Phi(\alpha)$, so $\Phi$ fails to be strictly increasing.

If $0<\beta<\omega$, then $\Phi(\omega) = \omega +\beta$, while $\bigcup_{n<\omega}\Phi(n) = \bigcup_{n<\omega} (n+\beta) = \omega$, so $\Phi$ fails to be continuous.

---

I agree that the solution you posted doesn't answer the question: it seems to me that it shows that the function $\alpha\mapsto \alpha+\beta\cdot\omega$ fails to be continuous for all non-zero $\beta$, rather than $\alpha\mapsto \alpha+\beta$.

But the same idea can be easily adapted to answer the question. I'm sure this is what the person who wrote the solution originally intended.

Suppose $\alpha<\beta\cdot\omega$. Then $\alpha\leq \beta\cdot n$ for some $n\in \omega$, so $$\Phi(\alpha) = \alpha+\beta \leq \beta\cdot n + \beta = \beta\cdot (n+1) < \beta\cdot \omega.$$  It follows that $\bigcup_{\alpha<\beta\cdot \omega}\Phi(\alpha) = \beta\cdot \omega$. But $$\Phi(\beta\cdot\omega) = \beta\cdot\omega + \beta = \beta\cdot(\omega+1).$$ So $\Phi$ fails to be continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex, and sorry for the late answer! Now this is much clearer, just one minor thing in the second part: you meant "It follows that $\bigcup_{\alpha<\beta\cdot \omega}\Phi(\alpha) \le \beta\cdot \omega$"?

Comment: Right, I've only explained $\leq$ (and this is all we need to show). But $\geq$ is easy, so we get $=$. See if you can work it out.

Comment: Oh right, so it comes from $\alpha<\Phi(\alpha)$, and so $\alpha<\beta\cdot\omega$ implies that $\alpha<\Phi(\alpha)\le\bigcup_{\alpha<\beta\cdot \omega}\Phi(\alpha)$. Anyway, that's not strictly necessary, since you have already proved that $\bigcup_{\alpha<\beta\cdot \omega}\Phi(\alpha) \le \beta\cdot \omega<  \beta\cdot(\omega+1)=\Phi(\beta\cdot\omega)$. Nevertheless, I should have been able to spot the equality earlier, ahah :D

Comment: @Davide exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, this is much easier than it's being made:

The key point is that **any normal function has a fixed point**, that is, if $\Phi$ is normal then there is some $\lambda$ such that $\Phi(\lambda)=\lambda$. This is easy to show - just consider the limit $\lambda$ of the sequence $$\omega,\Phi(\omega),\Phi(\Phi(\omega)), ....$$ (note that since $\Phi$ is normal, this sequence is increasing so does indeed have a unique limit).

But $\alpha\mapsto\alpha+\beta$ doesn't have any fixed points as long as $\beta>0$.

Comment: Thanks Noah, but I would consider that a fact stronger than needed. Indeed, later in the exam question I'm mentioning, I need to prove the existence of a fixed point. But it's good to think that such an argument is possible!